# How to get rid of "Download the react dev tools "?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      '__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__': '({ isDisabled: true })'
    })
```

I see comments suggesting to use this but I dont know where this should go. Should it go in webpacker/development.js. And even if I put it there, I still see the console log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should belong to `config/webpack/environment.js` or `config/webpack/development.js`

Try inserting it into `config/webpack/environment.js`:

```js
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
// ... other code

const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('DefinePlugin', new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      '__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__': '({ isDisabled: true })'
}))

// ... other code
module.exports = environment
```

Or into `config/webpack/development.js`:

```js
process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'

const environment = require('./environment')
const webpack = require('webpack')

environment.plugins.append('DefinePlugin', new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      '__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__': '({ isDisabled: true })'
}))

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

Comment: it's saying `environment.plugins.append('DefinePlugin', new webpack.DefinePlugin({   ReferenceError: webpack is not defined`

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. It thought that line was generated by default. Updated the answer.